# Emulation of an Orrery

Tags: motor, design

Orrery is a clockwork model of the solar system. I am trying to emulate one in 2D. Now, to emulate, I need to know what goes on inside. Can someone please explain the basic principle behind the clockwork? Or direct me to a resource that will explain all the machinery inside a simple Orrery.

Answer (score 1):

An [orrery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orrery) just represents the different speeds at which planets orbit the sun by careful selection of gear ratios.

[Here is a set of plans that define the gears themselves](http://zeamon.com/wordpress/?page_id=468), but you could calculate the necessary ratios from the [orbital period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period) of each planet.

In code, it would be something like:

```
timestep = 0
while True:
    timestep = timestep + 1
    for each planet:
        theta = (timestep / orbital_period(planet)) % 360
        draw(planet, theta)
```

Comment: Ah! I think you got the question wrong. When I said emulate I meant I would be emulating the clockwork mechanism (gears and stuff) in Box2D

Comment: You should update your question with that information, as well as describing where in Box2D you are stuck.